# TargetInvocationException Was Unhandled When Using fileWriter.Write()

Tags: vb.net, exception, filewriter

I have a project in VB.NET that creates a byte array of an image input then creates a file of the image in .jpg format. Here is the code:

```
Dim fileWriter As New System.IO.FileStream(filePath,System.IO.FileMode.Create)
fileWriter.Write(imageBuf, 0, imageBuf.Length)
fileWriter.Close()
```

Once the code runs, I get the following error right after the second line executes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I did take a look at similar posts on this site, however none of them seems to be relevant to mine. I would appreciate your input.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value in `filePath`?  I've seen this error (IIRC) when the path wasn't valid.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Following your idea I found that the issue is with the folder! I initially though files couldn't be written into the folder because it was in Read Only mode. However, I was able to write into different folders at the same level using the same code that were in Read Only mode. I still don't know what is the matter with the folder, but I created a new folder and I am able to write in it just fine. Thank you.